# Prevent from uploading older version of a GAV to a nexus repository

Tags: maven-3, nexus, nexus3

Is there a way to ensure that only newer versions of an artifact are uploaded to a nexus repository?

I see there is an option to not allow redeploying an artifact but I am looking for a way to prevent an older version from getting uploaded.

Comment: @dur Maven seems to have a way to order versions based on different formats it supports: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855.

Comment: @dur we follow the major.minor.build format and wondering if there is any support in nexus to prevent an older version from getting uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus cannot determine which version is older or which is latest, this is something you will have to perform, however you can restrict nexus on uploading the same version but restricting the deployment policy to "Disable Redeploy"